# My Xcode shows too many devices with different IDs, how to delete duplicate devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have too many simulators:

[image: Huge list of different simulators each with a UUID string]

I would like to delete the duplicate devices, but not sure where to do that.

Comment: Click on "Add Additional Simulator", you can remove them from that new window. Else it's `Window/Devices and Silmulator` from the menu.

Comment: try this https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/306566

Answer (score 3):

Go to your terminal and write this:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```

When updating Xcode, I used this command for obsolete Simulator versions and it cleaned up almost 50GB for me

Comment: I did use the command, but nothing happened for me

Comment: @MohmedAnisAgwan same for me

Answer (score 1):

You can access your installed simulators under Window>Devices & Simulators in Xcode.

Selecting the Simulators tab in this window, you'll see a list of all installed simulators. If you select one or more simulators from the list, then press backspace (or right click, delete), you'll be prompted to remove the simulator.

[image: delete simulator]